# Using azure-ad-b2c with splunk

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, saml, splunk

I've beed trying to get azure-ad-b2c to be a IDP with localaccounts for Splunk SAML SSO.
with
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-get-started
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/connect-with-saml-service-providers

Presently I've got different error messages like

- Verification of SAML assertion using the IDP's certificate provided
  failed. Unknown signer of SAML response
- Verification of SAML
  assertion using the IDP's certificate provided failed. Error: failed
  to verify signature with cert

Also, given I get this to work, I still need to extract security group association and exposed to Splunk.  I think this [article](https://mrochon.azurewebsites.net/2019/05/06/using-groups-in-azure-ad-b2c/) is relevant....

Anyone have a good writeup to get this going?

Brgds
Kristen

Answer (score 0):

If this is a new B2C setup, have you used the MS Azure test app to verify?

https://samltestapp2.azurewebsites.net/SP

Based on the error,  it sounds like Splunk needs to trust the certificate used for SAML signatures.